# Replacing entire table row in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table and I want to be able to replace an entire row with data from another page.
I want to be able to replace the data over and over again without refreshing the page. I have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/8gsa01gp/21/) but can't understand why   `$("#rowid").replaceWith(newdata);`does not seem work. If I change this to   `$("#2").replaceWith(newdata);` then row 2 with id=2 gets replaced as expected.

What have I got wrong? Many thanks.

html

```
<div class="container">

<table class="table" id="data_table"><tbody><tr><th></th> <th></th><th></th>
</tr>
<tr class="table" id="1"><td></td><td class="prod">First cell</td><td class="prod">Second cell</td><td class="prod">Third Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>

  <tr class="table" id="2"><td></td><td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td><td class="prod">Fifth cell</td><td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn2" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>


  <tr class="table" id="3"><td></td><td class="prod">Seventh</td><td class="prod">Eighth</td><td class="prod">Ninth</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn3" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>
  <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#data_table').on("click", "tr",function(){
 var btnid= $(this).attr("id");//Find button ID
 var rowid= $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");//Find row ID

   var newdata= '<tr class="table" id="4"><td></td><td class="prod">10</td><td class="prod">11</td><td class="prod">12</td><td><button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>'; //Data to be replaced

alert(rowid); 
   $("#rowid").replaceWith(newdata); //Replace clicked row with data

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$("#rowid")` you need to use `$("#"+rowid)` since `rowid` is the variable not a selector.

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */$('#data_table').on("click", "tr",function(){
 var btnid= $(this).attr("id");//Find button ID
 var rowid= $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");//Find row ID
 
   var newdata= '<tr class="table" id="4"><td></td><td class="prod">10</td><td class="prod">11</td><td class="prod">12</td><td><button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>';
   
//alert(rowid);
   $("#"+rowid).replaceWith(newdata);
  
    });
    
  
    
   //$("#"+btn).click(function(){
  
    
  // });
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<table class="table" id="data_table"><tbody><tr><th></th> <th></th><th></th>
</tr>
<tr class="table" id="1"><td></td><td class="prod">First cell</td><td class="prod">Second cell</td><td class="prod">Third Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>

  <tr class="table" id="2"><td></td><td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td><td class="prod">Fifth cell</td><td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn2" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>


  <tr class="table" id="3"><td></td><td class="prod">Seventh</td><td class="prod">Eighth</td><td class="prod">Ninth</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn3" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>
  <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue is because `rowid` is a variable, yet you are using it as a string literal. You need to fix this by concatenating the value of the variable to the selector:

```
$('#' + rowid).replaceWith(newdata);
```

```js
$('#data_table').on("click", "tr", function() {
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id"); //Find button ID
  var rowid = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id"); //Find row ID

  var newdata = '<tr class="table" id="4"><td></td><td class="prod">10</td><td class="prod">11</td><td class="prod">12</td><td><button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>';
  
  $('#' + rowid).replaceWith(newdata);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" id="data_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table" id="1">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">First cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Second cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Third Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table" id="2">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Fifth cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn2" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table" id="3">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Seventh</td>
        <td class="prod">Eighth</td>
        <td class="prod">Ninth</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn3" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

That being said, the pattern of using incremental `id` attributes on each and every `tr` is not a good idea. For a start it makes the HTML harder to maintain and the JS needlessly complex.

A much better approach is to use DOM traversal to find the `tr` related to the clicked button. You can also place the HTML content to be used as the source within the DOM so that the HTML and JS are not coupled too closely. With those points in mind, try this:

```js
$('#data_table').on("click", ".add-row", function() {
  var $newdata = $('#data_table tr.clone').clone().removeClass('clone');
  $(this).closest('tr').replaceWith($newdata);
});
```

```css
.clone {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" id="data_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clone">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">10</td>
        <td class="prod">11</td>
        <td class="prod">12</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">First cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Second cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Third Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Fifth cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Seventh</td>
        <td class="prod">Eighth</td>
        <td class="prod">Ninth</td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: probably wants button in selector too

Comment: Indeed, just edited to include a method which clones the HTML instead of hard-coding it in to the JS

Comment: That's really helpful and thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `"#rowid"` is a string literal.
Try:  `$("#"+rowid)`
You need to access your variable.