# How to replace two table rows with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table and I want to replace two rows
with data from another page. I've got it to work with one table row but whenever I try to replace two rows it **replaces** one and **adds** another. Is this possible? 
I've made a fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/uvkj5m12/8/)

(*The reason I'm doing this is in the final version the second row is an accordion with the same data but displayed differently*).
Many thanks.

Html

```
<div class="container">

<table class="table" id="data_table"><tbody><tr><th></th> <th></th><th></th>
</tr>
<tr class="table"><td></td><td class="prod">First cell</td><td class="prod">Second cell</td><td class="prod">Third Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table_hidden"><td></td><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td><td></td></tr>

  <tr class="table"><td></td><td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td><td class="prod">Fifth cell</td><td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn2" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table_hidden"><td></td><td>4a</td><td>5a</td><td>6a</td><td></td></tr>


  <tr class="table"><td></td><td class="prod">Seventh</td><td class="prod">Eighth</td><td class="prod">Ninth</td><td> <button type="button" id="btn3" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr>

  <tr class="table_hidden"><td></td><td>7a</td><td>8a</td><td>9a</td><td></td></tr>
  <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#data_table').on("click", ".add-row", function() {


   var newdata= '<tr class="table"><td></td><td class="prod">10</td><td class="prod">11</td><td class="prod">12</td><td><button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr><tr class="table_hidden"><td></td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td></td></tr>';

   $(this).closest('tr').replaceWith(newdata);


    });
```

Comment: Did you [already ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570872/replacing-entire-table-row-in-dynamic-table/50570904#50570904)? The answers you have there seem to cover this already.

Comment: I asked a similar question and you have me an excellent answer but I am now struggling with how to replace two table rows.

Comment: Do you mean two rows in a single click?

Comment: Yes, two rows. The second row will eventually be hidden ( it will be displayed on a click). I'just can't figure out the correct way to replace both rows and have gotten very confused with the correct way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove 2 rows, you can delete the 2nd row first. Use `replaceWith` to replace the `<tr>` with 2 `<tr>`s

```js
$('#data_table').on("click", ".add-row", function() {
  var newdata = '<tr class="table"><td></td><td class="prod">10</td><td class="prod">11</td><td class="prod">12</td><td><button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td></tr><tr class="table_hidden"><td></td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td></td></tr>';

  $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').remove(); //Remove the next tr
  $(this).closest('tr').replaceWith(newdata); //Replace the current tr
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <table class="table" id="data_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">First cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Second cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Third Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn1" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table_hidden">
        <td></td>
        <td>1a</td>
        <td>2a</td>
        <td>3a</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Fourth Cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Fifth cell</td>
        <td class="prod">Sixth Cell</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn2" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table_hidden">
        <td></td>
        <td>4a</td>
        <td>5a</td>
        <td>6a</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>


      <tr class="table">
        <td></td>
        <td class="prod">Seventh</td>
        <td class="prod">Eighth</td>
        <td class="prod">Ninth</td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="btn3" class="add-row">Replace Row</button></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table_hidden">
        <td></td>
        <td>7a</td>
        <td>8a</td>
        <td>9a</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```